# Python: ElementTree If Else Condition

Tags: python, xml, if-statement, elementtree

I would like to print the value with the condition:
if the IsRecommended.text is true, it will print the value in the same tree only.
But the result now is it print all the values included the IsRecommended.text is false.

```
<Settings>
       <Setting>                  
          <Address>15:0</Address>
          <Comments />
          <Conditions />
          <IsSingleEnded>true</IsSingleEnded>
          <IsVisibilityExternal>false</IsVisibilityExternal>
          <MetaDatas />
          <SettingName>123</SettingName>
       </Setting>
       <Setting>                  
          <Address>18:0</Address>
          <Comments />
          <Conditions />
          <IsSingleEnded>true</IsSingleEnded>
          <IsVisibilityExternal>false</IsVisibilityExternal>
          <MetaDatas />
          <SettingName>abc</SettingName>
       </Setting>
       <Strings>
          <String>
            <value>1</value>
            <IsRecommended>false</IsRecommended>
          </String>
          <String>
            <value>2</value>
            <IsRecommended>true</IsRecommended>
          </String>
        </Strings>
    </Setting>
</Settings>
```

Here is my code:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

with open('abc.xml', 'rt') as f:
    tree = ElementTree.parse(f)
    #address1 = tree.findall('.//Address')
    #print address1.node.tag

with open("expected.txt", "w") as text_file:
    for setting in tree.findall('.//Setting'):
        address = setting.find('./Address')
        setting_name = setting.find('./SettingName')
        strings = setting.find('./Strings')
        is_recommended = None
        for string in strings.findall('./String'):
            for is_recommended in string.findall('./IsRecommended'):
                for value in strings.findall('.//value'):
                    if is_recommended is not None and is_recommended.text == 'true':
                        print value.text
                        text_file.write("{} {} {}\n".format(setting_name.text, address.text, value.text))
```

Any error in my code? How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your xml example seems to be malformed, you are closing a `<Setting>` tag but you have not openned it anywhere. Assumming that is only a copy-paste mistake, since you say you get all values in the output file.

The actual issue is in line -

```
for value in strings.findall('.//value'):
```

Inside each `String` tag, you are again checking values from its parent `Strings` , which is wrong, you need to check the value from the `String` tag only. And if you are sure each `String` tag only have 1 value and 1 `IsRecommended` tag, you do not need loops for that. You can do -

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

with open('abc.xml', 'rt') as f:
    tree = ElementTree.parse(f)
    #address1 = tree.findall('.//Address')
    #print address1.node.tag

with open("expected.txt", "w") as text_file:
    for setting in tree.findall('.//Setting'):
        address = setting.find('./Address')
        setting_name = setting.find('./SettingName')
        strings = setting.find('./Strings')
        if strings is not None:
            for string in strings.findall('./String'):
                is_recommended = string.find('./IsRecommended')
                value = string.find('./value')
                 if is_recommended is not None and is_recommended.text == 'true':
                    print value.text
                    text_file.write("{} {} {}\n".format(setting_name.text, address.text, value.text))
```

Comment: Sorry what? What do you mean duplicate keys? Where do you see keys?

Comment: Again, sorry but I do not understand what you are saying , you may want to first have a look at element tree documentation - https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html . It is a module for xml parsing.

Comment: `<country>` I do not see it anywhere? Where do you see that?